# compareTo not working - Testing all combinations of two strings

Tags: java

My class is defined as follows...

```
public static class Connection implements Comparable<Connection>
```

Here is my compareTo method.

```
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Connection o) {

        List<String> combinations = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(String lcp : LCP_ORDER){
            for(String state : STATE_ORDER){
                combinations.add(lcp + state);
            }
        }

        int result = combinations.indexOf(this.lifecycle + this.connEditState) - combinations.indexOf(o.getLifecycle() + o.getConnEditState());

        return  result;
    }
```

So on the output I will have..

```
this lcp = PR
this state = null
o lcp = AD
o state = null
result = 0
```

This should not return 0 because the lcp is different. I need a way to test all the combinations of two strings. Suggestions?

Comment: The output is a print out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your list of `combinations`, you're most likely not adding the variants where one of the two values is `null`.

In the test you're executing, the state is `null`, so the combination will not be found. The call to `indexOf` will return `-1` in both cases, and `- 1 - (-1)` will result in `0`.

---

As a side note:

1. If possible, you probably want to store the combinations as a constant instead of building the list every time `compareTo` is called.
2. You might want to separate the `lcp` from the `state` with some sort of separator character to avoid clashes (the case where `lcp1 + state1 == lcp2 + state2`, e.g. `"ab" + "c" == "a" + "bc"`) if such a risk exists.
3. You probably don't even need to build the list of combinations, and can implement the `compareTo` method by just comparing the indexes of `lcp` and `state` in `LCP_ORDER` and `STATE_ORDER` separately:

   ```
   @Override
   public int compareTo(Connection o) {
       int orderIndex = LCP_ORDER.indexOf(this.lifecyle)
               - LCP_ORDER.indexOf(o.lifecyle);

       if (orderIndex != 0) {
           return orderIndex;
       }

       int stateIndex = STATE_ORDER.indexOf(this.connEditState)
               - STATE_ORDER.indexOf(o.connEditState);

       return stateIndex;
   }
   ```